# Largest divisible subgroup not an intersection

Tags: abelian-groups, divisible-groups

Is there an abelian group $G$ for which the largest divisible subgroup of $G$ (given by the sum of all divisible subgroups) is not the intersection of all subgroups of the form $nG$ over the positive integers $n$?

Note that if $ny=x \in G$, then for any positive integer $m$, if $z \in G$ and $nmz=x$, then of course $nmz=ny$, but one cannot in general "cancel" the $n$ to get $mz=y$. Cancellation is possible only if one knows that $0$ is the only element of $G$ whose order divides $n$, which in particular holds if $G$ is torsionfree.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following construction works:

Let $F = \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} \Bbb Z$. Define $H \leqslant F$ by $\langle e_1 - 2e_2, e_1 - 3e_3, \ldots \rangle$.
Set $G = F/H$.

Then, $\overline{e_1} \in nG$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.
On the other hand, given any $x \in F$ with $\overline{e_1} = 2 \overline{x}$, there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $x \notin nG$.
This shows that $\overline{e_1}$ cannot be in any divisible subgroup of $G$, even though it is in the intersection of all $nG$.

---

For the proofs of the above statements, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4264722/427810).
Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459200/427810) to note that the biggest divisible subgroup consists of all totally divisible elements, instead of all divisible elements.