# Divisibility in an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ a abelian group. I recall that:

1. Let $g\in G$, $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$; i write $n \mid g$ iff exists $x\in G$ such that $g=nx$.
2. $G$ is said *divisible* iff $n \mid g$ $\forall g\in G, n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.
3. $G$ has a largest divisible subgroup: the divisible part ${\rm Div}(G)$.
4. $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}, \forall g\in G$ the $p$-height is defined as $h_p(g)=\max\{n\in\mathbb{N}: g\in p^nG\}$. I pose $h_p(g)=\infty$ iff $ g\in p^nG$ $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know that: $G$ is divisible iff $h_p(g)=\infty$ $\forall g\in G, p\in\mathbb{P}$.

I am asking if:

1. ${\rm Div}(G)=\{g\in G: n \mid g$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$.
2. ${\rm Div}(G)=\{g\in G: h_p(g)=\infty$ $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}\}$.

In 1) and 2) the inclusion $\subseteq$ is obvious; I'm not sure that $\supseteq$ it's true, and I ask for help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb P$? Positive integers? Primes?

Comment: P=set of (positive) Primes

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div}\newcommand{\QED}{\qquad \blacksquare}$The equalities do **not** hold. I give a counterexample of a group $G$ and an element $g \in G$ which belongs to both the $X$s but not in $\Div(G)$.
Let us set up some terminology and notation first.

**Notation.** $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of positive integers, i.e., $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

**Definition.** An element $g \in G$ is called *divisible* if $n \mid g$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Let $F = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots = \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

We shall use $e_{n}$ to denote the element with $1$ in the $n$-th coordinate and $0$ in all other coordinates.
Let $H$ be the subgroup of $F$ generated by elements of the form $e_{1} - n e_{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*} 
 H := \langle e_{1} - 2 e_{2}, e_{1} - 3 e_{3}, e_{1} - 4 e_{4}, \ldots\rangle.
\end{equation*}
Lastly, set $G = F/H$. For an element $x \in F$, we shall denote its image in $G$ by $\overline{x}$.

Let $X$ be as in the first part, i.e., $X$ is the set of all divisible elements of $G$.

**Claim 1.** $\overline{e_{1}} \in X$.
*Proof.* Let $n \ge 1$ be given. Then, consider $e_{n} \in F$. By definition of $H$, we have $e_1 - n e_{n} \in H$ or $\overline{e_{1}} = n \overline{e_{n}}$ in $G$. $\QED$

Now, we show that $\overline{e_{1}} \notin \Div(G)$. In particular, this shows that $X \neq \Div(G)$. We do this by proving the following claim.

**Claim 2.** Let $x \in F$ be any element such that $\overline{e_{1}} = 2 \overline{x}$. Then, there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K \nmid \overline{x}$ in $G$.

Note that $\overline{e_{1}} \notin \Div(G)$ follows immediately from **Claim 2.** Indeed, if $\overline{e_{1}}$ were in $\Div(G)$, then there must be $\overline{x} \in \Div(G)$ such that $2\overline{x} = \overline{e_{1}}$. But the above claim shows that no such $\overline{x}$ is divisible.

*Proof of Claim 2.* This proof is a bit ugly but fairly straightforward.
Let $x$ be as given. Then, write
\begin{equation*} 
 x = (n_{1}, \ldots, n_{N}, 0, 0, \ldots).
\end{equation*}
(Each $n_{i}$ is an integer. Moreover, as will be clear from the next equations, we must have $N \geqslant 2$.)

Then, we have
\begin{equation} \tag{$1$}
 e_{1} - 2x = (1 - 2n_{1}, -2n_{2}, \ldots, -2n_{N}, 0, 0, \ldots).
\end{equation}
The above element is zero in the quotient $F/H$. Thus, the above element is in $H$. Thus, we must have
\begin{equation*} 
 e_{1} - 2x = k_{2}(e_{1} - 2e_{2}) + \cdots + k_{N}(e_{1} - Ne_{N})
\end{equation*}
for some integers $k_{1}, \ldots, k_{N}$. (Since the coordinates in $(1)$ after the $N$-th position are $0$, we only need to go up until $k_{N}$.)

Writing the above in tuple notation, we get
\begin{equation} \tag{$2$}
 e_{1} - 2x = (k_{2} + \cdots + k_{N}, -2k_{2}, -3k_{3}, \ldots, -Nk_{N}, 0, 0, \ldots).
\end{equation}

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives us a system of linear equations as
\begin{align*} 
 1 - 2n_{1} & = k_{2} + \cdots + k_{N}, \tag{$\ast$}\\
 2n_{2} & = 2k_{2}, \\
 2n_{3} & = 3k_{3}, \\
 & \vdots \\
 2n_{N} &= Nk_{N}.
\end{align*}

Note that the sum $k_{2} + \cdots + k_{N}$ is odd. Thus, there is some $K \in \{2, \ldots, N\}$ such that $k_{K}$ is odd. But on the other hand, we have
\begin{equation*} 
 2n_{K} = Kk_{K} \quad\text{or}\quad \frac{n_{K}}{K} = \frac{k_{K}}{2}.
\end{equation*}
Since $k_{K}$ is odd, we see that $\frac{k_{K}}{2} = \frac{n_{K}}{K}$ is not an integer. In other words, $K \nmid n_{K}$.

We now claim that there is no $y \in F$ such that $\overline{x} = K \overline{y}$.
For the sake of contradiction, assume that there is such a $y$. As before, write $y$ as
\begin{equation*} 
 y = (m_{1}, \ldots, m_{M}, 0, 0, \ldots)
\end{equation*}
with $M \ge N$.

Then, we have
\begin{equation*} 
 x - Ky = (n_{1} - Km_{1}, \ldots, n_{K} - Km_{K}, \ast, \ast, \ldots).
\end{equation*}
As before, this is equal to an element of $H$. Since $K \ge 2$, the $K$-th coordinate of $x - Ky$ must be divisible by $K$. (See $(2)$ for the appearance of an arbitrary element of $H$).
But we have already seen that
\begin{equation*} 
 n_{K} - Km_{K} \equiv n_{K} \not\equiv 0 \mod K.
\end{equation*}
This is the desired contradiction. $\QED$

---

Note that the same example works for (ii) as well. Indeed, the $X$ in part (i) is clearly a subset of the $X$ in part (ii) and for this $G$, we have already seen that
\begin{equation*} 
 \Div(G) \subsetneq X_{\text{(i)}} \subseteq X_{\text{(ii)}}.
\end{equation*}

---

**Additional remark.** Note that in (i), you were asking if the set of all divisible elements is precisely equal to $\Div(G)$. As I have shown, that is not the case.
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459200/427810) completely characterises what $\Div(G)$ looks like. It is the set of *totally divisible* elements (as defined in that answer). Essentially, just being divisible is not enough to ensure that you can find a "divisor" that is again divisible.
For example, looking at our $G$, we see that $\overline{e_{1}} = 2 \overline{e_{2}}$ but there is no $x$ such that $\overline{e_{2}} = 2 \overline{x}$.
Totally divisible ensures that you have a "compatible family of divisors" which guarantees that each divisor is itself divisible. The answer there shows that this is necessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

To show that something is a subset of $\mathrm{Div}(G)$, you will need to use the definition: $\mathrm{Div}(G)$ is the largest divisible subgroup of $G$.

(I should point something out here: it's not obvious that such a subgroup always exists! This needs proving, but I'll assume you've done that.)

Anyway, to show that $X \subseteq \mathrm{Div}(G)$ for some set $X$, you must show that $X$ is contained in a divisible subgroup of $G$. Since $\mathrm{Div}(G)$ is the largest divisible subgroup, it will then contain $X$.

Here, in (1) we have $X = \{g \in G : n \mid g \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$. We need to show this is contained in a divisible subgroup of $G$. But actually, this *is* a divisible subgroup of $G$! Show this, and you will be done.

The same idea works for (2). Please give this a shot and let us know if you're still stuck!

Comment: When you say "divisible subgroup", do you mean (a) every element of that subgroup $H$ is divisible in $G$, i.e., for every $x \in H$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists $y \in \color{red}{G}$ such that $ny = x$, or (b) $H$ considered as a group is divisible, i.e, for every $x \in H$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists $y \in \color{red}{H}$ such that $ny = x$?

Comment: The latter; a subgroup which is itself a divisible group.

Comment: (1) $X$ is a subgroup of $G$. I would like to proof that $X$ is divisible: let $g\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Then $n|g$ and exist $x\in G$ with $g=nx$. The problem is that $x\in G$ and not $x\in X$. (2) have simiar problem.

Comment: Then I am a bit uncertain as to whether the $X$ in (1) is divisible. I don't have a counterexample but my issue is due to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924884/), about the construction of ${\rm Div}(G)$. If what you say works, then ${\rm Div}(G)$ is simply the set of all divisible elements, but one of the answers there requires the elements to be totally divisible. Now maybe the two are equivalent but the "obvious" proof doesn't seem to work. (And I suspect that if that were actually correct, then one of the answers would have pointed it out.)

Comment: The obvious proof being: Let $x \in X$ and $n \geqslant 1$. Then, there exists $y \in G$ such that $ny = x$. I'd want to show that this $y$ belongs to $X$. To this end, let $m \geqslant 1$ be arbitrary. Then, there exists $z \in G$ such that $x = nmz$ and thus, $ny = nmz$ or $n(y - mz) = 0$. It isn't clear whether one can conclude $y = mz$. (Of course, there could possibly be a different value of $y$ that works...)

Comment: I think I now have a counterexample depicting exactly what I thought would go wrong, which I have posted as an answer. Let me know if you find any errors. (Alternately, you could put a proof of why you think $X$ is divisible and I could compare that with my example.)

Comment: Hi, do you have a proof of showing why $X$ is divisible? The other answer seems to show that that is not always the case.